# Highstocks - How to change the default Zoom

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This question results from hours of googling highstocks, zoom, extremes, ranges, and every other  possible variation of the words, all resulting in some variation of custom functions for high *charts* answers.

Is there a way to simply **change the default zoom to 1 month instead of 3 months** in **HighStocks** (not HighCharts) without writing a function to calculate what it happens to be?

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can change it by the following code:

```
new Highcharts.StockChart({
    .
    .
    .
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0
    }
});
```

You can take a look the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/QnvrR/.

The default buttons are:

```
buttons: [{
    type: 'month',
    count: 1,
    text: '1m'
}, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: '3m'
}, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 6,
    text: '6m'
}, {
    type: 'ytd',
    text: 'YTD'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: '1y'
}, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'All'
}]
```

So, you have to change the number of the selected according to what you want.

Reference

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.buttons

Comment: Wow...now THATS intuitive,lol.  Thanks!  Don't have access to try it, but will be accepting your answer as soon as I can - thx!

Comment: If you look the reference: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#rangeSelector--selected you can see that there're many options to custom it ;)

Comment: I've always loved configurability and options, but this one has my head spinning with terms, or it's use of them....lol....seems pretty easy once you know what you're looking for!

Comment: Of course, and the link above can help you to find what you need.

Comment: Just in case anybody is confused as to where to place the button config, you can look at the reference or place the button config inside the `rangeSelector` config where `selected` lies.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom Links are index of an array, so if you want select the default render, set this params:
rangeSelector: { selected: index_of_array },
in my case for select "all" have setted selected: 5