# How do I adjust the initial range in hc_navigator

Tags: r, highcharts

I am using the highcharter package (which is great) to plot time series data in R and have added a navigation to my chart using the following function:

```
hc_navigator()
```

I want to pass in an argument that specifies the initial focus of the range of the navigator.

This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/series-data/

Notice that navigator range defaults to 3 months, rather than the entire series.

I looked through the documentation and I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is not the `hc_navigator`.

You need to search about *highstock set default zoom* in google which lead you to this highcharts question/answer [Highstocks - How to change the default Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107752/highstocks-how-to-change-the-default-zoom). You need to use `rangeSelector` options.

So in highcharter: `hc_rangeSelector(selected = 2)`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have a follow-up I hope you can answer. `hc_rangeSelector()` appears to only works with highstocks. But I am plotting multiple series using `hc_add_series_list()` (per your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093229/multiple-series-in-highcharter-r-stacked-barchart), which would seem to preclude me from creating a chart from xts objects unless I explicitly added each one using `hc_add_series_xts()`. Is there a way to either apply the `rangeSelector` options to a non-highstock chart OR to pass in a list of time series to a highstock?

Comment: Hi, you can do `highcharts(type = "stock") %>% hc_add_series_list()`. Tell me if this work for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work:

`library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

testData <- data_frame(
  day = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-30"), by = "day"),
  var1 = c(1:30),
  var2 = c(40:11)
)

testList <- testData %>%
  gather(key, value, -day) %>%
  group_by(name = key) %>%  
  do(data = as.xts(.$value, .$day)) %>%
  list_parse

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(testList)`

Comment: Aps, sorry. Look, the `hc_add_series_xts` is a shortcut which transform the `xts` object into a format which highcharts can read/use (https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/R/shortcuts-ts-xts.R#L113) meanwhile `hc_add_series_list` assume the data is ready. So you need to change the `do({  })` code by `do(data = {
    timestamps <- datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(.$day))
    list_parse2(data.frame(timestamps, .$value))
  })`. Let me if this work for you.