# R Shiny Highcharter - How to use hc_rangeSelector()

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm plotting a financial intra-day time serie on an R-Shiny project using the highcharter package. I'm using the following code for the server part in order to get the output (note that xtsPrices() is a function that returns an xts intraday time-serie):

```
output$plot <- renderHighchart({

y <- xtsPrices()

highchart() %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)%>%
  hc_add_series_ohlc(y) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_538(colors = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                            chart = list(backgroundColor = "white") ))
})
```

I read in the documentation that in order to personalize zoom buttons I have to deal with the hc_rangeSelector() function, but I don't understand how to specify them in this R-Shiny environment as shown for the javascript case in [Highstock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector). In particular - because it's an intra-day time-serie - I would need buttons like "20min", "1h", "3h", "1D", etc.

Comment: This question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665958/how-do-i-adjust-the-initial-range-in-hc-navigator/39666504#39666504. You need `highcharts(type = "stock") %>% ` to know option in rangeSelector visit http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For intra-day data you can do something like this:

```
hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series_ohlc(y, yAxis = 0, name = "Sample Data", id = "T1",smoothed=TRUE,forced=TRUE,groupPixelWidth=24) %>% 
  hc_rangeSelector( buttons = list(
    list(type = 'all', text = 'All'),
    list(type = 'hour', count = 2, text = '2h'),
    list(type = 'hour', count = 1, text = '1h'),
    list(type = 'minute', count = 30, text = '30m'),
    list(type = 'minute', count = 10, text = '10m'),
    list(type = 'minute', count = 5, text = '5m')
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_538(colors = c("red", "blue", "green"),chart = list(backgroundColor = "white") ))
hc
```

[image]

Comment: Np, happy to help! you should provide sample data next time I had to query my database to make the plot