# Highcharter: range slider on the heatmap and labels different from values

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have a very large heatmap, and I was wondering if adding a range slider to it is possible, like in [this example.](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/intraday-breaks)

Sample code:

```
   data <- data.frame(
      X = c(1:12000),
      Y = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 4000),
      Value = rnorm(12000)
    )


data %>%
  hchart(type = "heatmap", hcaes(x = X, y = Y, value = Value)) %>%
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", verticalAlign = "top", align = "right")
```

Answer (score 1):

In higcharts, the function is called rangeSelector. You can use `hc_rangeSelector` in `highcharter`.

There's already a post about this: [R Shiny Highcharter - How to use hc_rangeSelector()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421331/r-shiny-highcharter-how-to-use-hc-rangeselector)

Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.